# How to use a CompuMethod with category linear

Tags: autosar

I have a query about how a compu-method with category linear works. For real, it could be a specific question about the tool, but I would like to know if I am right about the compu-method.

As I know by [constr_1158-TPS-Software Component Template] the definition of the reference a compu-method is restricted to a Compu-Method of either category Bitfield or text-table. So, what I want to make is a Compu-method with category linear and it is not allowed in implementation datatype. In addition, an Application datatype with a Compu-method with category linear is allowed.

Also, I know that an application data type does not generate code in C. How could be reflected this compu-method in my code?

Basically what I have is a network with a CompuMethod with category linear and I would like to reflect this on the RTE before being pass to the App. In the RTE specification, I found an example that what I want to do [Example 4.9]. It is slightly different because I just have an ECU and a network, but basically it is the same (I think so).

What I expect:

[image]

What did I do?

1. From a database, I got the compu-method.
2. Made an Application data type and referenced a compu-method to it.
3. A data mapping to an implementation data type.
4. Referenced that data mapping to the SWC.

Should I do other things? I am not really sure if it is the tool, or I did something wrong. I think it is something basic, but I have been working on Autosar for few months.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you refer Application datatype in the VariableDataPrototype?

Comment: Do you mean reference it in the application port interface? If so, yes I did.

Comment: In SenderReceiver Interface you have VariableDataPrototype there you have to refer the APD and refer that VDP in the port interface.is it the same you configure?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I have an interface with a variable data prototype that refer the application datatype.

Comment: As per my knowledge the way you configured is proper. But check once the values given in the compu-method(Numerator and denominator) are proper or not. Read the generator user-manual, it may help.

Comment: I personally read your question here over and over, but I have no idea, what your question actually is all about. Can you reformulate this in an understandable english format?

Comment: Sorry for my English and thanks for you wanted to help me. I solve it. I have configured the port properly. It was a problem with the tool I was using on.

Answer (score 1):

> How could be reflected this compu-method in my code?

To my knowledge, there is only one reason for a linear `CompuMethod` to appear in the code: data conversion where a piece of data in one representation (e.g. a `dataElement` in a `PPortPrototype`) is converted into another representation (the corresponding `dataElement` in the connected `RPortPrototype`). The conversion, however, is done by the AUTOSAR RTE and therefore hidden from the application code.

In contrast, a `CompuMethod` of category `TEXTTABLE` leaves a trace in the code because symbols are defined for the textual labels such that they can be used in the application code.